# How to make recipients in MFMessageComposeViewController using a variable

Tags: ios, objective-c, sms, message

I'm trying to use the MFMessageComposer to pre-fill sms for the user. I am trying use a variable that is stored in a mutable array and use that number to pre-fill the phone number. However it doesn't work with the code below at the recipient part. I've tried changing it to a string, adding it to the array. The phone just doesn't do anything.

However if I do a manual number using @[@"123132131235"]; for the recipients it would work.

```
- (IBAction)smsSend:(id)sender {

    {
        MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
        [controller setMessageComposeDelegate:self];
        if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])
        {

            controller.recipients =  [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[Detail valueForKey:@"Phone"], nil];

            NSLog(@"%@",[Detail valueForKey:@"Phone"]);

            controller.body = @"Hello testing";

            [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:NULL];

        }   else {
            NSLog(@"cannot send");
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me.

Cheers,
Tony.

Comment: Can you do `NSLog(@"%@",[Detail valueForKey:@"Phone"])` and see what you are getting?

Comment: What is `[Detail valueForKey:@"Phone"]`? What kind of object does it return?

Comment: when I do NSLog(@"%@",[Detail valueForKey:@"Phone"]) i get the right number like 123456789.

Comment: [Detail valueForKey:@"Phone"], Detail is the mutable array and Phone is an object I added to the mutable array from core data.

Comment: Could you log `controller.recipients` ? I'm also wondering if `[[Detail valueForKey:@"Phone"] class]` returns really a `NSString` object.

Comment: I logged 'controller.recipients' it shows the correct value. It's just not opening the message.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
- (IBAction)smsSend:(id)sender  
{
 {
    MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
    [controller setMessageComposeDelegate:self];
    if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])
    {
        controller.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[Detail valueForKey:@"Phone"], nil];

        controller.body = @"Hello testing";

        [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:NULL];
    }   
    else 
    {
        NSLog(@"cannot send");
    }
 }
}
```

The only change I have made is recipient array allocation. Recipient array is not the array that you own so instead of `[NSArray alloc]` you should directly initialise array with objects.

`initWithObject` returns an array with a retain count of 1, i.e. you own the array and you must release it at some point to prevent memory leaks.

`arrayWithObject` returns an autoreleased array so you do not have to worry about releasing it when you don't need it anymore (but if you store it in an instance variable, you should retain it to prevent the autorelease pool from freeing it)

Comment: It doesn't work if you remove the alloc. It says "No known class method for selector with 'initWithObjects' "

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I have edited code can you check now?

Comment: I've actually tried that and I just tried again. It just flashes a bit and returns to the same screen.

Comment: Just to confirm, you are checking on a real device with sim card, correct?

Comment: Yes I am checking on a real device but no sim card. But I tested it with @[@"123132131235"]; and it still took me to the messages. But if I replace it with my the variable it just flashes and does not show.